# bash script: different results when called with or without sudo

Tags: bash, scripts, sudo

In Ubuntu 16.04.3, I have a very simple bash script:

**test.sh**

```
[[ 0 == 0 ]] && result="true" || result="false"
echo $result
echo $USER $SHELL $0
```

When I call it as the non-root user `me` or as `root`, it works as expected. If I use `sudo ./test.sh`, it complains about a syntax error:

```
$ ./test.sh
true
me /bin/bash ./test.sh

$ sudo su
# ./test.sh 
true
root /bin/bash ./test.sh

# exit
$ sudo ./test.sh
./test.sh: 1: ./test.sh: [[: not found
false
root /bin/bash ./test.sh
```

What could be causing this? How can I fix it so that `me` can use this script both normally and with `sudo`?

Comment: Pro tip: [there's no point in running `sudo su`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/218169/22222). Just run `sudo -i` or `sudo -s` instead.

Comment: @terdon `sudo -i` changes the location to `/root`. `sudo su` or `sudo -s` don't change the directory location.

Comment: Yes, read the question I linked to before for why. And sorry, I've edited my previous comment, I had forgotten to mention `-s`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Every script begins with a [Shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)), without it the shell starting your script doesn't know which interpreter should run your script<sup>1</sup> and might – as in the case of `sudo ./script.sh` here – run it with `sh`, which in Ubuntu 16.04 is linked to `dash`. The [conditional expression](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/conditional_expression) `[[` is a [`bash` compound command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/bash.1.html#contenttoc18), so `dash` doesn't know how to handle it and throws the error you encountered.

The solution here is to add

```
#!/bin/bash
```

as the first line of your script. You may get the same result when you call it explicitly with `sudo bash ./script.sh`, but a shebang is the way to go.
To check which shell runs your script, add `echo $0` to it. That's *not the same as* `echo $SHELL`, citing [wiki.archlinux.org](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/environment_variables#Examples):

> SHELL contains the path to the user's preferred shell. Note that this
>   is not necessarily the shell that is currently running, although Bash
>   sets this variable on startup.

1: As you started `./test.sh` with `bash` it just assumed `bash`, the same goes for the `sudo su` subshell.

Comment: Also note that bash runs a script without shebang using bash, not `/bin/sh`.

Comment: @dessert That fixes it. Thanks! How can I check *from within a script* which shell is running it? (`echo $0` gives me the name of the script: `./test.sh`)

Comment: @JamesNewton no portable way, AFAIK, but you can check what `/proc/$$/exe` points to. Also you can test various variables like `$BASH_VERSION`, `$ZSH_VERSION`, etc. (but dash doesn't set any such variable)

Answer (score 5):

As [@dessert explained](https://askubuntu.com/a/980122/85695), the problem here is that your script doesn't have a [shebang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)). Without a shebang, `sudo` will default to attempting to run the file using `/bin/sh`. I couldn't find it documented anywhere, but I confirmed by checking the `sudo` source code where I found the following in the file `pathnames.h`:

```
#ifndef _PATH_BSHELL
#define _PATH_BSHELL "/bin/sh"
#endif /* _PATH_BSHELL */
```

This means "set if the variable `_PATH_BSHELL` isn't defined, set it to `/bin/sh`". Then, in the `configure` script included in the source tarball, we have:

```
for p in "/bin/bash" "/usr/bin/sh" "/sbin/sh" "/usr/sbin/sh" "/bin/ksh" "/usr/bin/ksh" "/bin/bash" "/usr/bin/bash"; do
    if test -f "$p"; then
    found=yes
    { $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: result: $p" >&5
$as_echo "$p" >&6; }
    cat >>confdefs.h <<EOF
#define _PATH_BSHELL "$p"
EOF

    break
    fi
done
```

This loop will look for `/bin/bash`, `/usr/bin/sh`, `/sbin/sh`, `/usr/sbin/sh` or `/bin/ksh` and then sets the `_PATH_BSHELL` to *whichever was found first*. Since `/bin/sh` was the first in the list and it exists, `_PATH_BSHELL` is set to `/bin/sh`. The result of all this is that the default shell of `sudo` unless otherwise defined is `/bin/sh`.

So, `sudo` will default to running things using `/bin/sh` and, on Ubuntu, that is a symlink to `dash`, a minimal POSIX compliant shell:

```
$ ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Feb 27  2015 /bin/sh -> dash
```

The `[[` construct is a bash feature, it isn't defined by the POSIX standard and isn't understood by `dash`:

```
$ bash -c '[[ true ]] && echo yes'
yes
$ dash -c '[[ true ]] && echo yes'
dash: 1: [[: not found
```

In detail, in the three invocations you tried:

1. `./test.sh`

   No `sudo`; in the absence of a shebang line, your shell will try to execute the file itself. Since you are running `bash`, this will effectively run `bash ./test.sh` and work.
2. `sudo su` followed by `./test.sh`.

   Here, you are starting a new shell for the user `root`. This will be whatever shell is defined in the `$SHELL` environment variable for that user and, on Ubuntu, root's default shell is `bash`:

   ```
   $ grep root /etc/passwd
   root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
   ```
3. `sudo ./test.sh`

   Here, you are letting `sudo` execute the command directly. Since its default shell is `/bin/sh` as explained above, this causes it to run the script with `/bin/sh`, which is `dash` and it fails since `dash` doesn't understand `[[`.

---

<sub>**Note**: the details of how `sudo` sets the default shell seem to be a bit more complex. I tried changing the files mentioned in my answer to point to `/bin/bash` but `sudo` was still defaulting to `/bin/sh`. So there must be some other places in the source code where the default shell is defined. Nevertheless, the main point (that `sudo` defaults to `sh`) still stands.</sub>

Comment: *I couldn't find it documented anywhere* – me neither, I just assumed it would use `/bin/sh` from the error message – what else could it possible be? The question is answered beautifully in [What shell does sudo use · SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37817693/what-shell-does-sudo-use), see also [`man sudo`, section COMMAND EXECUTION](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/sudo.8.html#contenttoc3). Turns out **`sudo` doesn't use an intermediate shell**!

Comment: @dessert yes, it uses its own implementation of the `execve` system call which defaults to `sh`. And no, intermediate shells are irrelevant, this isn't about the shell that runs the command but about the shell interpreter used to read the shell script given. So no, it doesn't launch an intermediate shell but it still needs a shell interpreter for shell scripts.